# Problema en función JavaScript para activar selects con información traída de una Base de datos

Tags: javascript, laravel

tengo dos problema tratando de implementar un función JavaScript en mi proyecto.
 *

### Mi primer problema:

*
 - Actualmente  la función que tengo me permite activar un select al introducir el numero "1" en el input con id=type. Lo que quiero es que ese valor me lo traiga de la Base de datos y según ese valor este activo o desactivado el select.

**Este es mi formulario: (Para traer datos de la base de datos empleo @foreach ($nombre_dotacion as $ver))**

```
<form action="{{ route ('asignacion_dotacion.store')}}" method="POST" name="fr">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dotacion" name="dotacion[]" value="{{$ver->id}}. {{  $ver->name}}" readonly>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cantidad_solicitada" name="cantidad_solicitada[]" value="{{  $ver->cantidad }}" readonly>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cantidad_disponible" name="cantidad_disponible[]" value="{{ $ver->new_quantity }}" readonly>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cantidad_asignada" name="cantidad_asignada[]" value="">
          </td>
          <div class="botones">
            <td>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="type" name="type[]" >
            </td>
          <td>
            <select  id="date" name="categoria" class="form-control" >
                <option selected>Seleccione...</option>
                <option value="1">Corto Plazo</option>
                <option value="2">Mediano Plazo</option>
                <option value="3">Largo Plazo</option>
            </select>
          </td>
        </div>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</form>
```

Yo puedo traer la información de la base de datos de forma correcta. 
El problema es que la función me tome ese valor y no uno introducido por teclado.

**Esta es la función Java Script que estoy empleando:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validar(form) {
        if(type.value==1){
            variable2.disabled=false
        }
        else{
            variable2.disabled=true
        }
    }

    var variable2 = document.getElementById("date");
    variable2.disabled = true;
    var type =document.getElementById("type");
    type.onkeyup = validar;
</script>
```

### Mi sengundo Problema

- La función se ejecuta bien para el primer input y el primer select. Pero en mi tabla tengo varios registros y la función debe funcionar igual para todos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que podrias hacer, es que directamente en el codigo, suponiendo que estas usando blade, comprobar si el valor esta en 1 o 0 para habilitar o no el selector, sin necesaidad de pasar por la funcion en javascript, al menos la primera vez.

```
<select  id="date" name="categoria" class="form-control" >
    <option>Seleccione...</option>
    <option value="1" @if ($ver->type == 1) selected="selected" @endif>Corto Plazo</option>
    <option value="2" @if ($ver->type == 2) selected="selected" @endif>Mediano Plazo</option>
    <option value="3" @if ($ver->type == 3) selected="selected" @endif>Largo Plazo</option>
</select>
```

Lo otro seria llamar a la funcion `validar` donde deberias setear el valor de `var type ='{{$ver->type}}';`

Todo este ejemplo suponiendo que el campo obtenido de la tabla se llama `type`

Sobre el segundo problema, lo que tendrias que hacer sería realizar una sola funcion donde pudieras obtener en los parametros el selector y el valor del input.

```js
function cambiaselector(selectorid, inputvalue){
    var selector = $('#'+selectorid+'');
    if(inputvalue==1){
      selector.prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
      selector.prop('disabled', true);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Tipo 1<input type="text" id="type" onChange="cambiaselector('date', this.value)"><br>
Tipo 1<input type="text" id="type" onChange="cambiaselector('date2', this.value)"><br>
<hr>
Selector 1
<select  id="date" name="categoria" class="form-control" >
    <option>Seleccione...</option>
    <option value="1">Corto Plazo</option>
    <option value="2">Mediano Plazo</option>
    <option value="3">Largo Plazo</option>
</select>
<br>
Selector 2
<select  id="date2" name="categoria" class="form-control" >
    <option>Seleccione...</option>
    <option value="1">Corto Plazo</option>
    <option value="2">Mediano Plazo</option>
    <option value="3">Largo Plazo</option>
</select>
```

Si ingresas 1 el selector se habilitara, si ingresas otra cosa se deshabilitara.
Espero te sirva

Answer (score 0):

Mil gracias Jolsalazar, me fue de bastante utilidad tu ayuda. 
Al final, resolví sin utilizar javascript, y aproveche las ventajas de blade.

El formulario me quedo algo así:

```
@if ($valor0 === 2)
     <select  id="date" name="categoria[$i]" class="form-control" disabled>
     <option selected >Seleccione...</option>
     <option value="1">Corto Plazo</option>
     <option value="2">Mediano Plazo</option>
     <option value="3">Largo Plazo</option>
                                  </select>
@elseif ($valor0 === 1)
 <select  id="date" name="categoria[$i]" class="form-control">
 <option selected >Seleccione...</option>
 <option value="1">Corto Plazo</option>
 <option value="2">Mediano Plazo</option>
  <option value="3">Largo Plazo</option>
</select>                             
 @endif
```

Lo agregue como un partials a mi tabla. Y el valor lo busco en mi controlador y lo paso a la vista en la variable valor0.

Gracias!